# Can I use multiple useEffect with same dependency array to handle multiple unrelated side effects without effecting the performance?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a useEffect managing different (2 or more) unrelated side effects. To improve code readability, I wanted to split them into multiple useEffect. Can I do this without hit on the performance?

Comment: Yes you can do that

Comment: @AhmedSbai So there will be no performance impact doing so?

Comment: I cannot think of a reason this can impact performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: Yes, you can use multiple `useEffect`s.

*Technically* running multiple `useEffect`s *might* be slower than just running one `useEffect`, but that is very likely absolutely **not relevant**. React is optimized for that, and calls many many functions all the time, so a few more `useEffect`s don't matter.

The effort you would have to make inside that single `useEffect` to handle your multiple cases might even be **slower** than just using multiple `useEffect`s, and you likely would loose a lot of readability.

React is a library that cares a lot about clean code, maintainability, readability, developer experience, and stuff like that, and accepts a little loss of performance for that. But react still has sophisticated **optimizations**, implemented by smart people, so it's still pretty performant.

I can't think of use cases where calling multiple `useEffect`s has a relevant impact on performance. Maybe tell your use case, if you think yours might be one of those.

Of course, if you e.g. iterate over the same large list in every `useEffect`, then that is slower that iterating only once in one single `useEffect`, but that's always true in every programming environment, that's not because of calling multiple `useEffect`s per se.